# Why 'series' object is not callable?

Tags: python

I have an assignment that needs to assign `df_confirmed_local` to a DataFrame of confirmed cases that are local or epidemiologically linked with a local case, but when I run my code, it raises an error.

```
df_confirmed_local = df_covid.loc
[
(df_covid["Confirmed/probable"] == "Confirmed")
    & (df_covid["Case classification"] == 'Local case')
    (df_covid["Case classification"] == "Epidemiologically linked with local case")
]

df_confirmed_local
```

Comment: You miss a `&` in the code

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: this looks like a typo, but adding the error text would greatly improve your Question!

Answer (score 2):

**Explanation:**

As mentioned by the answer by @ArunJose, and the comment by @Minh-Long Luu, you have a boolean condition missing between the 2nd and 3rd condition, however it's an `|`.

```
(column1 == foo) & (column2 == bar) | (column2 == baz)
```

Each column is a [`pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html) object. When used in a boolean expression, it also returns a Series of booleans.  If you miss one of the conditions (`|`) it looks like a function call to Python, leading to the "object is not callable" error:

```
(column2 == bar) (column2 == baz)  # looks like pd.Series()
```

That said, you probably should group your conditions with parentheses to reflect the correct precedence:

```
(column1 == foo) & ((column2 == bar) | (column2 == baz))
```

Something like this:

```py
df_confirmed_local = df_covid.loc[
    (df_covid["Confirmed/probable"] == "Confirmed")
    & (
        (df_covid["Case classification"] == "Local case")
        | (
            df_covid["Case classification"]
            == "Epidemiologically linked with local case"
        )
    )
]
```